# How to add a custom object database to libgit2?

Tags: git, libgit2

I try to understand how to implement a custom object database in [libgit2](https://libgit2.org/). As the main entry point I already checked out the example repository called [libgit2-backends](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2-backends) which implements examples for `memcached`, `mysql`, `redis` and `sqlite3`.

But I still don't understand how to plug these into libgit2? Am I plugging in a shared library that libgit2 can load? Or do I compile libgit2 from scratch with the corresponding backend sources? What is the scope of such backend? Any insights are highly appreciated!

Motivation: By default git and libgit **packs/compresses** objects. In my case I would like to implement a backend that does not do that. (Yes, there is LFS, but I try to find a libgit2-only solution)

Comment: "I would like to implement a backend that does not do that." . . . what's wrong with `git config core.compression 0`?

Comment: Good idea but it doesn't seem to be supported by `libgit2`

Comment: You could try reaching on the libgit2 [slack](http://slack.libgit2.org/)?

Comment: Also , in tge libgit2 API docs, the [odb section](https://libgit2.org/libgit2/#HEAD/group/odb) might be helpful, especially the `
git_odb_backend_loose` function

Answer (score 7):

You're able to achieve that with [`git_odb_open`](https://libgit2.org/libgit2/#v0.18.0/group/odb/git_odb_open). It's part of the official [libgit2 API](https://libgit2.org/libgit2/#v0.18.0).

Basically, `git_odb_open` *"[c]reate[s] a new object database and automatically add[s] the two default backends"* (quote taken from [here](https://libgit2.org/libgit2/#v0.18.0/group/odb/git_odb_open)). If you take a look at the [ligbit2 GitHub repository](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2), you can find the `GIT_EXTERN(int) git_odb_open(git_odb **out, const char *objects_dir);` within `odb.h` (in general, I suggest to check out all the [odb functions](https://libgit2.org/libgit2/#v0.18.0/group/odb)). Anyhow, the comments below the function are extremely useful:

```
/**
 * Add a custom backend to an existing Object DB
 *
 * The backends are checked in relative ordering, based on the
 * value of the `priority` parameter.
 *
 * Read <odb_backends.h> for more information.
 *
 * @param odb database to add the backend to
 * @param backend pointer to a git_odb_backend instance
 * @param priority Value for ordering the backends queue
 * @return 0 on success; error code otherwise
 */
```

*Kinda unfortunate that those notes aren't included on the standard documentation.* Anyway, here you can see the important `@param` for a backend pointer to the instance itself. On a slight off-topic note, I'd suggest checking out the code of [`odb_backend.h`](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/blob/main/include/git2/sys/odb_backend.h) as well (fortunately, ligbit2 is very well documented).

By the way (for the sake of completeness), I should mention you also can plug a custom backend into an already existing odb via [`git_odb_add_backend`](https://libgit2.org/libgit2/#v0.18.0/group/odb/git_odb_add_backend) (obviously you got the pointer there as well), though it requires you to have an existing database to begin with  . In case you're looking add an alternative to already-existing backends, i.e. in your case one one that doesn't compresses objects, you may go with [`git_odb_add_alternate`](https://libgit2.org/libgit2/#v0.18.0/group/odb/git_odb_add_alternate).

Comment: Either @HelloWorld or Daniel Stephens, please let me know whether I've covered all of your questions and/or if there are any questions left! Hope I could help you out.